# Python: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, comparison, logistic-regression

I came across a problem with comparing the predictions of my model with the labels of training set. The arrays I'm using have shapes:

> Training set (200000, 28, 28) (200000,)
> Validation set (10000, 28, 28) (10000,)
> Test set (10000, 28, 28) (10000,)

However, when checking the accuracy with the function:

```
def accuracy(predictions, labels):
    return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
          / predictions.shape[0])
```

It's giving me:

> C:\Users\Arslan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
> """

And it gives the accuracy as 0% for all datasets.

*I think we cannot compare the arrays using '=='*. How could I compare the arrays in the right way instead?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I assume the error occurs in this expression:

```
np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
```

can you tell us something about the 2 arrays, `predictions`, `labels`?  The usual stuff - dtype, shape, some sample values.  Maybe go the extra step and show the `np.argmax(...)` for each.

In `numpy` you can compare arrays of the same size, but it has become pickier about comparing arrays that don't match in size:

```
In [522]: np.arange(10)==np.arange(5,15)
Out[522]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [523]: np.arange(10)==np.arange(5,14)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[523]: False
```

Comment: Thanks. dimensions of the two matrices were messed up. It went smooth after rearranging the elements in the matrices.

Answer (score 17):

This error is telling you that the comparisson you're performing doesn't really make sense, since both arrays have different shapes, hence it can't perform elementwise comparisson. Here's an example:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,5,(3,2))
y = np.random.randint(0,5,(5,7))
```

Where attempting to do `x==y` will yield:

> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
> x==y

The right way to do this, would be to use [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html), which checks equality of both shape and elements:

```
np.array_equal(x,y)
# False
```

In the case of floats, [`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) is more suited, since it allows to control both the relative and absolute tolerance of the comparisson result. Here's an example:

```
x = np.random.random((400,34))
y = x.round(6)

np.array_equal(x,y)
# False
np.allclose(x,y)
# False
np.allclose(x,y, atol=1e-05)
# True
```

Comment: But what if I want the count of different elements?

Answer (score -7):

I solved this by upgrading python to 3.6.4 (latest)

```
conda update python
```

Comment: This did not help me.

Comment: I think the point here is this error/behavior could be related to a Python or package version.

Comment: yeah, in some cases this might help, but downgrading a package version is often not the desired solution (I entered here just to find how to use the last method to do it, not to start a dependency hell), many times even not possible (imagine a team project in which you cannot just switch library versions)