# Comparing two arrays throws a warning. Any workaround for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have 2 np.array() as below. When I compare the two using "==", I get an output but with a deprecation warning. There is no warning when comparing 2 arrays with a same matrix.

What's the workaround to get still the same result but with no warning?

Thank you so much!

```
x = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
x

Out: array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

y = np.array([[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]])
y

Out: array([[ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])

x == y

Out: False

**C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.**
```

Screenshot:

Comment: Where is the Screenshot ?

Answer (score 2):

This error is telling you that the comparisson you're performing doesn't really make sense, since both arrays have different shapes, hence it can't perform elementwise comparisson:

```
x==y
```

> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
> x==y

The right way to do this, would be to use [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html), which checks equality of both shape and elements:

```
np.array_equal(x,y)
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equiv.html):

```
np.array_equal(x,y)  # test if same shape, same elements values

np.array_equiv(x,y)  # test if broadcastable shape, same elements values
```

and also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

x and y have different shapes.

You can compare two Numpy arrays with the same shape element-wise way.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576275/7394312) maybe helpful.